# Microsoft Office Word 365 Border around SVG graphics

Tags: microsoft-word, adobe-illustrator, svg, border

I have exported my Illustrator file as an SVG and successfully imported it in Word 365. Now I want to create a black border **around** the graphic (in word).

Whenever I try to do so it just changes the lines **inside** the SVG to black (see image).

---

Left side is what it looks like and right side is what it actually looks like.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sosxz.png)

Is there anything I can do apart from creating the border in Illustrator?

Answer (score 0):

There's at least two options that should work:

- Draw an excel table around the object in Word, then create an outside border

  - Insert - Table - choose table rows and colums
  - Manually select all the cells in the table >  Borders > All Borders, then Outside Borders 
     *All Borders removes the default borders*
- Draw a shape, such as a square, then remove it's fill

  - Insert > Shapes > Select and draw shape > Right-click on shape > Fill - no fill

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I'd really prefer any solution that is not a workaround.